# Rails 3 Nested Resources views(index)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

So I finally got my urls to work using nested resources but there's still one little problem. I got the mysite.com/profile/1/photos/new page and form to work properly but the mysite.com/profile/1/photos page does not work. I am not sure why at this point.

My nested routes look like so.

```
resources :profiles do
 resources :photos
end
```

The index page will not work, it gives me the following error

```
undefined method `user_id'
```

This is what I have in my photos_controller.rb file

```
def index
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
  @photo = Photo.find_by_id(params[:all])
end

def show
  @profile = Profile.find(params[:profile_id])
  @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
end
```

Here is the index form. This form will not work.

```
<% title "Photos" %>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>User</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
<% for photo in ([@photos, @profile]) %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= photo.user_id %></td>
    <td><%= photo.title %></td>
    <td><%= photo.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Show", profile_photo_path %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_profile_photo_path%></td>
    <td><%= link_to "Destroy", profile_photo, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysite.com/photos`  should be `mysite.com/profiles/:profile_id/photos` and 
`photos/edit` should be `profiles/:profile_id/photo/:id/edit` 
link helpers will looks like

```
link_to "Photos", profile_photos_path(@profile)
link_to "Edit photo", profile_edit_photo_path(@profile,@photo)
```

Check out rails guides about [nested resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)